# Class "App\Http\Controllers\Customer" not found

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomerController extends Controller {
  protected function index(){
    $data = Customer::join('orders','orders.cus_id', '=', 'customers.id')
    ->get(['customers.id', 'customers.name', 'customers.address', 'customers.phone', 'customers.age', 'orders.item', 'orders.qty']);

    return view('Member.Jointable', compact('data'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Add `use App\Customer;` or `use App\Models\Customer;` to the top of your file. You didn't import `Customer`, so your code tries to resolve it to the current Namespace `App\Http\Controllers`, but that's typically not where the file is.

Comment: The answer of @TimLewis is good if you aren't in a previous versions (^8.0) of Laravel where Model class are no more directly in app folder

Comment: ^ Correct; that's why I said "or". In previous versions, Models were in `App`, in newer, they're in `App\Models`. This wasn't tagged with a specific version, so best to include both.

Answer (score 2):

you must specify where to find the class Customer, and i think, its in app/Models, so you have to solution
you can write `\App\Models\Customer` any time or write `Customer` but for this last case, you must insert after namespace declaration `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` which Customer is used here.
The appropriate code is `use App\Models\Customer;`

Then your code will now know which Customer class to require.
Your error, its because, you didn't have a Customer class in the same folder with your controller, and this is normal, Model must be in another folder `app/Models`